# how many roots does $p(z) = z^{10} + 100z + 1$ in $\{z:|z|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, rouches-theorem

how many roots does $p(z) = z^{10} + 100z + 1$ has in $\{z:|z|<1\}$

Can I use Rouche theorem and say that on that region $|100z|=100>2=1+1=|z^{10}|+1$

and thus the number of roots for p(z) is the same as the number of roots for $100z$ which is $1$ (the root is $0$)?
is it that simple?

Comment: What does $|z<1|$ mean?And why is $|100z| = 100$???

Comment: If Nerval circles a tree one time, always keeping a distance of 100 units, and is leash is 2 units, then his lobster walks around the tree one time.

Comment: Yes, it is that simple, but you should clean up the solution a bit.  It is not so that "on that region" ($|z|<1$) $100|z|=100$ nor that $|z^{10}|+1=2$  This is true on the boundary of the region.

Comment: From Luca Savant's answer below, you also know that the unique root of $p(z)$ in the unit disc $\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|z|<1\big\}$ is a negative real number $t$.  In fact, $$-\dfrac{1}{99}<t<-\dfrac{1}{100}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

$p(z)=z^{10}+100z+1$ has only two real roots. This can be shown by differentiating: $p'(z)=10z^9+100$. So the only real root of $p'(z)$ is $p'(-\sqrt[9]{10})=0$. Studying the sign of this polynomial it's easy to demonstrate that $p(z)$ is decreasing from $(-\infty ; -\sqrt[9]{10})$ and increasing from $(-\sqrt[9]{10} ; +\infty$. Because $p(z)$ tends to positive infinity for $z\to \pm \infty$ and $p(-\sqrt[9]{10})<0$, $p$ has only two real roots: one between $(-\infty ; -\sqrt[9]{10}<-1)$ and the other between $(-\sqrt[9]{10} ; 0 (p(0)=1>0))$. So there is just real root of $p(z)$ whom absolute value is less than one and it isn't zero ($p(0)=1=\neq 0).

Comment: The question does not ask about the real roots. (Actually learning a subject before attempting to answer questions about it, might be a plus.)